# Overriding test execution status for a custom exception when using Specflow

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I'm using specflow with Nunit. When my tests are executed if a particular exception is thrown, I would like to set the status of my tests as Warning instead of Fail.

I have looked as updating the Nunit status, but Nunit test status seems readonly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this would work, I remember doing something similar while ago, but don't have the code anymore.
Check this property `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result` (nunit3)

You can check the value in aftereach, and if it is Failed, and whatever other conditions should be met, you can `Assert.Warn("Whatever");`